# How can I save the location of every single pixel of my image in c#?

Tags: c#, image, pixel

I am writing a programme that I need to save the location of every single pixel in my bitmap image in an array and later on in need to for example randomly turn off 300 of black pixels randomly. However I am not sure how to do that. I have written the following code but of course it does not work. Can anyone please tell me the right way of doing that?

Comment: What is all this nonsense? I assume you have a few build errors yeah? Fix them first, if you need help with them then add the specific errors to your question

Comment: Nice - you're not even trying to be *passively* agressive :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will open an image into memory, and then copy the pixel data into a 2d array.  It then randomly converts 300 pixels in the 2d array to black.  As an added bonus, it then saves the pixel data back into the bitmap object, and saves the file back to disk.

**I edited the code to ensure 300 distinct pixels were selected.**

```
        int x = 0, y = 0;

        ///Get Data
        Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("mold.jpg");
        Color[,] pixelData = new Color[myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height];

        for (y = 0; y < myBitmap.Height; y++)
            for (x = 0; x < myBitmap.Width; x++)
                pixelData[x,y] = myBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);


        ///Randomly convert 3 pixels to black
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Point> Used = new List<Point>();  

        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        {
            x = rand.Next(0, myBitmap.Width);
            y = rand.Next(0, myBitmap.Height);

            //Ensure we use 300 distinct pixels
            while (Used.Contains(new Point(x,y)) || pixelData[x,y] != Color.Black)
            {
                x = rand.Next(0, myBitmap.Width);
                y = rand.Next(0, myBitmap.Height);
            }
            Used.Add(new Point(x, y));   //Store the pixel we have used

            pixelData[x, y] = Color.White;
        }


        ///Save the new image
        for (y = 0; y < myBitmap.Height; y++)
            for (x = 0; x < myBitmap.Width; x++)
                myBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, pixelData[x, y]);

        myBitmap.Save("mold2.jpg");
```

Comment: It helps people greatly if you explain what your code does.

Comment: @Thorsten It does what he asked.  It also has comments.

Comment: I know, I'm just trying to say that posting just code is sometimes not a good solution without some explanation.

Comment: No problem.  I added some explanation.

Comment: could you please let me know what does "List<Point> Used = new List<Point>();" do?

Comment: thank you for your code, i think that i couldn't explaine what i need exactly; i need to turn off 300 pixels ONLY from black area of my image (my image is made of black and white pixels), not the entire image!

Comment: @user3266873 ok, can you explain what you mean by "turn off"?

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation, i mean to make the black pixel, white.

Comment: @user3266873 ok, i updated the code to change 300 random black pixels to white.  If the image does not have 300 black pixels, it will crash with an endless loop.  This is also highly inefficient because your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: Jon, thank you for your good comment. is that possible to say instead of fixed number of pixels (i.g. 300 px) we work with percentage (for example 70% of the black pixels turn to white?)

Comment: Is your entire picture black to begin with?

Comment: No, i have a white bmp image (100x100 pixel) which has a black character printed on it. i want to store the location of only black pixels (from the character) and then randomly make some of them white. this is the story actually;)

Comment: Are you trying to create a captcha? If so, this is a baaaad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The locations of every pixel are constant (every pixel has exactly one x and one y coordinate) so the requirement of *save the location of every single pixel* is vague.

I guess what you try to do is: Turn 300 pixels in an image black, but save the previous color so you can restore single pixels?

You could try this:

```
class PixelHelper
{
    public Point Coordinate;
    public Color PixelColor;
}

PixelHelper[] pixelBackup = new PixelHelper[300];

Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
{
    int xRandom = r.Next(bmp.Width);
    int yRandom = r.Next(bmp.Height);

    Color c = bmp.GetPixel(xRandom, yRandom);
    PixelHelper[i] = new PixelHelper() { Point = new Point(xRandom, yRandom), PixelColor = c };
}
```

After that the `pixelBackup` array contains 300 objects that contain a coordinate and the previous color.

---

EDIT: I guess from the comment that you want to turn 300 random black pixels white and then save the result as an image again?

```
Random r = new Random();

int n = 0;
while (n < 300)
{
    int xRandom = r.Next(bmp.Width);
    int yRandom = r.Next(bmp.Height);

    if (bmp.GetPixel(xRandom, yRandom) == Color.Black)
    {
        bmp.SetPixel(xRandom, yRandom, Color.White);
        n++;
    }
}

bmp.Save(<filename>);
```

This turns 300 distinct pixels in your image from black to white. The `while` loop is used so I can increase `n` only if a black pixel is hit. If the random coordinate hits a white pixel, another pixel is picked.

Please note that this code loops forever in case there are less than 300 pixels in your image in total.

Comment: My image is actually made of only black and white colour. What I need to do is recognise the black area of my image (foreground) and then for example turn 300 pixels of black pixels off randomly and saves the pout put image.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "turn off a pixel". A black pixel is a black pixel, a white one is white, what's an *off* pixel?

Comment: i mean to make the black pixel, white.